# Can I see my edit suggestions?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, profile-page, activity-tab

Is there a way to see how many of my suggested edits are accepted?

Comment: Is http://stackoverflow.com/users/1469980/tolga-evcimen?tab=activity&sort=revisions what you're looking for? (Also check the next two tabs)

Comment: Via SEDE it is possible to view all rejected/approved or even waiting approval. See [this answer for "How can I see all my rejected edits?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/104579/) on Meta.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

By going on your own profile, under "Activity" and "All actions", you can view: Revisions, Reviews, Suggestion, etc as shown in the image below.

Edits are shown under "Revisions".

[image: screenshot: Activity, All actions, Revisions]

Note:  if the screen is not wide enough the navbar with the "All actions" choice may not appear at all. At least in early 2023 this was the case.

---

Alternatively, a list of *your* suggested edits may be reached with link:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: The tab is now called "All Actions". Then look under Revisions.

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416085/where-to-view-edited-posts#comment895369_416085) could be included (since this is a duplicate target).