# View own tag wiki edit history approvals and rejections

Tags: support, tag-wiki

Is there anywhere I can view a list of the tag wiki edits I've made and which ones were approved / rejected?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I see my edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253684/can-i-see-my-edits)

Comment: @gnat No, this question wants to filter for tag wiki edits. There is no way to do that on the web frontend, but it can be done with the SEDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Simply go [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1922144/dcc?tab=activity&sort=suggestions)

Click on the *suggested edit* link to the ones of the tag wiki. Then you can see if it has been approved or rejected or pending and how each reviewer voted on your suggestion.

---

An easier way to find them, seems to be, by running [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/218565/my-rejected-edits) Just drop your user id *(1922144)* in there and click run *(and prove your a human)*.

Comment: Thanks. However, I assume it's not really possible to quickly find the ones that were rejected without drilling into each one individually?

Comment: Outstanding. Thank you. I have actually never known of this site before now.