# Where to view edited posts

Tags: support

I wanted to view my edits in a post that are currently not accepted and the edits which are accepted. I can only see the number of edited posts, but not the actual posts. Where can I find this?

Comment: In profile, under Activity->All Actions. https://stackoverflow.com/users/15747757/rohith-nambiar?tab=activity&sort=suggestions

Comment: Here's a link that works for everyone: https://stackoverflow.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=suggestions :D